# using PDFLibNet to save pdf page images

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm using PDFLibNet to save a thumb of a PDF page. The PictureBox works okay and shows the image, but it is saved as an absolutely white (blank) image!

```
PDFWrapper _pdfDoc = new PDFWrapper();
_pdfDoc.LoadPDF("d:\\bb.pdf");

PDFPage page = _pdfDoc.Pages[1];

Bitmap b = (Bitmap)page.LoadThumbnail(Convert.ToInt32(width), Convert.ToInt32(height));

pictureBox1.Image = b;

b.Save("D:\\a.jpg");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the **_pdfDoc.IsJpgBusy** property. While the main thread processes thumbnails

```
while (_pdfDoc.IsJpgBusy)
{
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give PDFLibNet sometime to finish rendering the bitmap.  The library renders thumbnails using a separate thread, and it will fire RenderThumbnailFinished event upon finishing.

```
RenderNotifyFinishedHandler handler = (s, e) => pictureBox1.Image.Save("D:\\a.jpg");
PDFWrapper _pdfDoc = new PDFWrapper(); 
_pdfDoc.LoadPDF("d:\\bb.pdf"); 

PDFPage page = _pdfDoc.Pages[1]; 
page.RenderThumbnailFinished += handler;

pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)page.LoadThumbnail(Convert.ToInt32(width), Convert.ToInt32(height));
```